# Angular2 to REST WebApi CORS issue

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, cors

I'm using an angular2 front end and WebApi backend.
The webapi is CORS enabled

```
var cors = new EnableCorsAttribute("*", "*", "*");
GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.EnableCors(cors);
```

and it works, because I have different sites (jQuery/Javascript) that use this api.  But with angular2 it doesn't.  I get the following message:

> Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Maybe is something related to "preflight request" ?

Comment: I read the docs for "Enabling Cross-Origin Requests in ASP.NET Web API" and you should have this header in the response. See section "How CORS Works" in this page: http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#how-it-works.

Comment: ***I'm closing it, because it is just a typo per OP.***

Comment: i think this problem in server properties see:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36825429/angular-2-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue in my Angular2 application.
The problem, as already stated, is that before every request made by the client a *preflight request* is sent to the server.

This kind of request have a type *OPTIONS*, and it's duty of the server to send back a *preflight response* with status 200 and headers set for accepting requests from that client.

This is my solution (with express):

```
// Domain you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:3000');

// Request methods you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE');

// Request headers you wish to allow
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'YOUR-CUSTOM-HEADERS-HERE');

// Set to true if you need the website to include cookies in  requests
res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);

// Check if preflight request
if (req.method === 'OPTIONS') {
    res.status(200);
    res.end();
}
else {
    // Pass to next layer of middleware
    next();
}
```

As you can see, i set the headers and then fetch if the request type is *OPTIONS*. In that case i send back a status 200 and end the response.

In this way, the client will be authorized and you will be also able to set your custom headers in all the requests.

Comment: Where did you put those lines?

Comment: Before the routes declaration.

Comment: It worked, thank you. 
I used [the CORS middleware](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors) but it didn't work. Why? Isn't this code doing the same thing?

Comment: Thanks a lot! this solution also work me with PHP-Angular

Answer (score 8):

Your error message tells that there is no `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` in the response of your call. It's something necessary to enable CORS for this request. It's not something related to Angular2.

This is triggered on the client side by the adding of the `Origin` header in the request. Do you have this header in your request? Do you use preflighted requests in your other applications. As a reminder:

- **Simple requests**. This use case applies if we use HTTP GET, HEAD and POST methods. In the case of POST methods, only content types with the following values are supported: `text/plain`, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` and `multipart/form-data`.
- **Preflighted requests**. When the "simple requests" use case doesn't apply, a first request (with the HTTP OPTIONS method) is made to check what can be done in the context of cross-domain requests.

Perhaps OPTIONS requests aren't correctly handled on the server side (don't return correct headers, ...).

What would be interested is to tell us on which requests the error occurs: the OPTIONS one or the target request. You can have a look at the **Network** tab in DevTools...

See these links for more details about how CORS works:

- http://restlet.com/blog/2015/12/15/understanding-and-using-cors/
- http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: +1 Gave me the right direction as I was struggling on the client, but the pre-flight error was because of server blockage of cors request with some headers. So have to allow all headers in my scenario.

Comment: @Thierry Templier can you take a look on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45444625/angular-2-httppost-to-oauth2/45444912?noredirect=1#comment77860961_45444912)?

Comment: Great explanation. Solution was given by @"Matteo Tosi"

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any options set into your web.config file for cors ? i.e something like `<add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"/>`

If yes make sure to remove that, and control the cors through the code only.

The Answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475808/cors-issues-on-webapi?answertab=active#tab-top) will help you.

Answer (score 1):

I know the question is not asking for PHP code. I got here because of this whole preflight thing and Angular2. When I looked at Matteo's answer, then I realized why the request to my server is coming back with 401. This because in the preflight browser does not send the Authorization token and therefore the server comes back with 401 and the browser thinks CORS is not allowed. Please be aware the code below should only be used in development server unless you know what you're doing.

In PHP you can do this:

```
if (strtolower($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']) === 'options') {
         header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN']);
         header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: POST, GET, OPTIONS');
         header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Range, Content-Disposition, Content-Type, Authorization');
         header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
         echo 'Allowed';
         exit;
}
```

OR Nginx

```
if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,X-CustomHeader,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain charset=UTF-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
```

Remember whatever other headers you're sending to the server you must be added to Access-Control-Allow-Headers list.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working with Angular 2 for the front-end and nodeJS (Expressjs) to the API

Angular 2 is working under localhost:3000 and express is working on localhost:8000

The problem happen when localhost:3000 tries call a URL with the POST method... The expressJS server rejects the call because it comes from another server (or port)

To solve the problem you should tell node js to accept calls from the localhost:3000 server...

[You can find a library (CORS) to avoid this problem in this link](https://medium.com/@ahsan.ayaz/how-to-handle-cors-in-an-angular2-and-node-express-applications-eb3de412abef#.a6d0nn5lc):

Answer (score 0):

You can add one add-on in your Firefox browser. It will work in your firefox browser like charm.  Cors Everywhere solved my problem.
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cors-everywhere/

Answer (score 0):

For development purpose add [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en) Chrome extension and enable cross-origin resource sharing.

Comment: Even if the extension works properly, this is a bad solution. The OP needs to set up CORS headers correctly **on his server**.

Comment: @sr9yar Yes, it's not a permanent solution but if you have some server dependency then you can go ahead with this chrome extension.

Answer (score 0):

I had also hard time with cors and angular 6.

when a request to the server is not a basic request, there is preflight request asking your server if it can answer to your request.

the server respond to that request should have those headers:

Access-Control-Allow-Origin // should be your domain

Access-Control-Allow-Headers // should be Accept, Origin, any other headers you might have.

Access-Control-Allow-Method // any methods you use

those are the " * ", " * ", " * " you added as Cors Attributes to accept all
but that only worked for me in dev mode when both client and server were on same machine.
after i moved to production with IIS server those values did not worked anymore especially because of the headers.

so it really easy to fix and it also working for IOS
instead * * * i added this to each controller:

```
[EnableCors(origins: "enter your domain here", headers: "authorization, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers", methods: "GET,POST", PreflightMaxAge = 600 // optional, SupportsCredentials = true // optional)]
```

you can read more in the article that helped me understand what i needed to do:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn532203.aspx

Hope it helps,
Tomer.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I used Owin and had to move the following line to the beginning of the startup

```
public class Startup
    {
        public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            ...
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the step for CROS ISSUE fixes in WEB API:

1. Enabling CORS required Headers in the Application. i.e. in “Application_BeginRequest” Method in “Global.asax” file for simple requests.
2. Placing  the below code in “web.config” file helped in CORS issue for preflight requests

   > ```
   > <system.webServer>
   >           <handlers>
   >             <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" />
   >             <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler" />
   >             <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0" />
   >           </handlers>
   >         </system.webServer>
   > ```

Reference:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api#enable-cors