# XMLHttpRequest cannot load ..Redirect has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: asp.net, angular, asp.net-web-api, adfs

I get error when I try to authetnticate user using ADFS STS. I get error as follows

> `XMLHttpRequest` cannot load https//authserver.com. Redirect from https://authserver.com to https://sts.mycompany.com/adfs/ls?wa=xxxx   ..... has been blocked by CORS policy: Request requires preflight, which is disallowed to follow cross-origin redirect

This is my scenario:

1. I have a Aungular2 App and a ASP.Net Web API for authenticating user.
2. This Web API is configured with ADFS/STS (On-Premises).
3. When I call this Web API directly, I can see it is redirecting to STS and return the required user credentials.

But, if I call this Web API from my Angular2 Module, I get an exception as given above.

Note: In Chrome Network, I could my angular service is being called 2 times.
First with Request Method: OPTIONS and second time with Request Method: Get, which returns Http 302.

Does anyone know how to resolve this issue.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular2 to REST WebApi CORS issue](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35202347/angular2-to-rest-webapi-cors-issue)

Comment: Nothing related to CORS on WebAPI though. Apparently ADFS doesn't support CORS. I have hit this wall too. Sucks