# Angular 2 HttpPost to Oauth2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, oauth, oauth-2.0, ionic2

I'm doing an `HttpPost` and is giving to me `error 401` but I've searched a lot on `StackOverflow` and I guess my call is OK, but the problem is when I execute this `HttpPost` on my `ARC` if I do not put the `authorization: user:password` it will popup a message saying this :

[image]

And I have to put it manually, **BUT** even if I do this :

[image]

It will pop up the `Authentication required`.

And it automatically changed to something like

> authorization: Basic JvbnyZpZpzZWNTcHNQX=

And now, the code looks like this :

My headers

```
 private headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' });
 private apiUrl = 'https://myApiTest/oauth/token';




var auth = "Basic " + Base64.encode("test:test");//Also have tried to copy the hexgenerated by ARC
    this.headers.append('authorization', auth);
    var body = 'grant_type=password&username=test@test.com&password=test';
     return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.http.post(this.apiUrl,body, {
            headers: this.headers
          })
        .subscribe(res => {
          alert(res.json());
          resolve(res.json());
        }, (err) => {
          reject(err);
          console.log(err);
        });
    });
```

And this is the error given by console

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myApiTest/oauth/token. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401
>   OPTIONS https://myApiTest/oauth/token 401 ()

### ***EDIT***

I've build it on my Android and it works fine seems like a problem with Google Chrome, I've found to use this : `C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C:/Chrome dev session2" --disable-web-security` but I'd like to use other way.

Comment: var body = 'grant_type=password&username=test@test.com&test=test';

Is it your real code? You are putting test=test instead of password=test..

Comment: missclick sorry, edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial guess would be that the API doesn't allows a cross domain request(CORS) More on CORS -> [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

You might need to add middle ware to your API to allow CORS
There might be some headers to set here
If you are using a node API you might wanna set headers.

`res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,OPTIONS');`

Comment: those options where I have to add on my API?

Comment: Yes.to ur backend server or api .
This is a cors issue. You can either do it programatically or there are ways to bypass in chrome for bypassing it for devolopment purposes

Comment: @Skizo-ozᴉʞS You need to add them as a middleware in ur API, such that every request goes through it. this is generally done before you declare your routes.

Comment: What about if the api accepts CORS already? how do I add the domains on my app?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable CORS.

In your [server](https://enable-cors.org/server.html) (`https://myApiTest`) and also your [client requests](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/).

- For any domain: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`
- For just one domain: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "https://your-exact-client-domain"`
- For multiple domains: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1850482/431841

Finally, I do not recommend you to disable the browser security, that should be your last resort.

Cheers!

Comment: On my server is set I guess, as I said when I run this on my Android device it works the only problem is when I do "ionic serve" it says the : XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://myApiTest/oauth/token. Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 401 OPTIONS https://myApiTest/oauth/token 401 (), so how do I enable cors on my client request? adding `Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`? I did already and doesn't work.

Comment: You are missing the `Origin header` in your client request

Comment: Something like this? `this.headers.append('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');`

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is server-side. For your client request: `this.headers.append('Origin': 'https://myApiTest');` if is not added automatically.

Comment: `http.es5.js:1256 Refused to set unsafe header "Origin"`

Comment: Have you checked this: http://blog.ionic.io/handling-cors-issues-in-ionic/